# How to get environment variable without process.env

Tags: node.js, npm, serve

How I can get environment variable without `process.env`, because it is undefined, due to launched app by `npm run serve` command.
p.s. My app is single Vue page.

Comment: question is deleted, created more simple topic.

Comment: Are you trying to access `process.env` in Node, or in the browser? If you're trying to do it in the browser, it's not going to work. If you're trying to do it in Node, `process.env` being `undefined` would be very weird, and the question you should be asking is why it's `undefined`. Running `npm run serve` will not cause that, unless the `serve` script is doing something very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

place the .env file in your project dir,
inside this file you can write key value variables. Like 
`SECRET=mySecret`
for mor info: [vue cli dock](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

Comment: "You can access them in your application code: console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)" but process.env is undefined in my case